# R - weighted adjacency matrix from two columns

Tags: r, igraph

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
AuthorID    ThreadID
   1           A
   2           A
   1           A
   2           A
   2           C
   3           B
   1           C
   4           B
   4           C
   4           C
```

where `AuthorID` identifies a particular author in a `ThreadID`. Threads can contain posts from many authors and authors can post in many threads.

I'm after a weighted adjacency matrix in R which I can use with igraph, that shows the number of times a particular `AuthorID` has communicated with another `AuthorID` within a `ThreadID`. So for these data the matrix should look like this (`AuthorID` as column and row headings):

```
   1  2  3  4
1  .  3  0  1
2  .  .  0  1
3  .  .  .  1
4  .  .  .  .
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do author 1 and 2 communicate through thread C, or should there be separate threads for 1-4 and 2-4?

Comment: [This article](https://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/working-with-bipartiteaffiliation-network-data-in-r/) provides a relatively gentle introduction to working with network data in R, and provides a solution to your problem (and more).

Comment: @aichao yep they both communicate through C

Comment: @WeihuangWong thanks for that, I'll check it out!

Comment: @disposedtrolley: then why is the weight between authors 1 and 2 not 3 (2 from thread A and 1 from thread C) but 2 in your desired output?

Comment: @aichao oops my bad. It should be 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using base R function. First, your sample data in a easily copy/paste-able format

```
dd<-read.table(text="AuthorID    ThreadID
   1           A
   2           A
   1           A
   2           A
   2           C
   3           B
   1           C
   4           B
   4           C
   4           C
", header=T)
```

Then you can do

```
x <- xtabs(~ThreadID+AuthorID, unique(dd)); 
mm <- crossprod(x,x)
mm[lower.tri(mm, TRUE)] <- NA
```

to get

```
        AuthorID
AuthorID  1  2  3  4
       1 NA  2  0  1
       2 NA NA  0  1
       3 NA NA NA  1
       4 NA NA NA NA
```

We use `xtabs` to count occurrences. We make sure to use `unique` so we don't count an author on a thread twice (to agree with your desired output. Then we use `crossprod` to get the author-author frequencies from the author-thread table. Finally we use `lower.tri` to get rid of the lower triangle as per your desired output.

Comment: Similarly, `dtab <- table(d) > 0L; dtab %*% t(dtab); dtab[lower.tri(dtab, TRUE)] <- NA`

Comment: How would I go about counting a pair of authors on a thread more than once (to get a weight of `3` between author `1` and `2`)?